# calling a web service that returns a zip file - java

Tags: java

I have been able to call a web service that returns a zip file, but it returns it in a format I am not familiar with. Here is a PART (not the whole thing) of the result I see in the console when I do a prinln on the string that contains the response:

oiÑ3(åË‰FMèÇqÎƒ„ï-®!?…QÒ M½^X¾=­…Xœ/P¸€Uú9 
zFèTvÄ¡ul\‰õö©ºûÅJF;P­¼e²ÉÀ«I÷3²ï*°ré>”Æà0i‡‡åE

I would like to get that zip file in one of my folders. Is there a way to translate those characters into my zip file downloaded on my machine?

EDIT: Here is the code that prints the stuff

```
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapRequest, soapEndpointUrl);

            ByteArrayOutputStream out1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            soapResponse.writeTo(out1);
            responseMsg = new String(out1.toByteArray());

            System.out.println(responseMsg); //DELETE THIS****-*-*-*
```

Other edit. I am mostly interested in being able to get the zip file FROM the String variable responseMsg,

Comment: Do you set the mimetype correctly?

Comment: What have you done so far to get the output you show? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You need to write the data to a file instead of to a string.

Comment: Thanks for the code. However, it still isn't complete and contains several compiler errors. In particular, there is no class or method and `soapConnection` is undefined. Please take some time to read the link I gave above.

Comment: `soapResponse.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("myfile.zip"));` (but don't forget to close the outputstream)

Comment: erwin, isn't that possible to get the zip file FROM the string response? rather than from the soap response variable

Comment: A zip file is *not* a String. You can't get binary data from a String unless it was first encoded in a proper way like `base64` - but you didn't do that. `new String(out1.toByteArray())` is not a proper way to deal with binary data.

Comment: I was trying to make the question shorter but the real context is: I still need to PARSE the string responseMsg(I can figure out how to do that) to get the part that corresponds to the zip file (the output part that I showed in the question). That is why I need to get the zip from the string, not from soapResponse. Is there a way to convert a string back to soapMessage to be able to use your sample code of soapResponse.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("myfile.zip");